# How to enable and disable default snippet keywords based on a particular scenario in angular ace editor

Tags: javascript, angular, code-snippets, ace-editor

I am using snippets in ace editor. I have created some custom snippets and added that to the existing snippets. But I want to hide the default snippets when I am showing custom snippets. How do I disable or hide the default snippets only in some particular scenarios?

Comment: Are you talking about `IDE`?

Comment: No, I have a javascript code for intellisense. I don't want to make any changes from IDE. I just want to enable and deisable the default snippets from my code.

Comment: Can you please show some example?

Comment: Do you want to hide the auto-complete keywords on any key event or any other scenario similar to it?

Comment: Case1 :
 I have some events like onAppVariablesReady, onPageReady etc. for which I have return custom snippets. When I type "Page.onAppVariablesReady", it should only show custom snippets but not all the default snippets.

Case2:
If I just do ctrl+space without entering any text, it should show all the default snippets and should not show custom snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom words list global

```
self.customSnippets = ["A", "B']; //your array of default custom snippets  

 editor.commands.addCommand({
     name: "bindDot",
     bindKey: { win: ".", mac: "." },
         exec: function () {
             var position = editor.selection.getCursor();
             var session = editor.session;

             var currentLine = (session.getDocument().getLine(position.row)).trim();
             var currentTokens = currentLine.slice(0, position.column).split(/\s+/);
             var currentCmd = currentTokens[0];
             if (!currentCmd) return;
             var lastToken = currentTokens[currentTokens.length - 1];
             var nextToken = currentTokens[currentTokens.length + 1];

             var filterValue = editor.session.getValue();
             if (filterValue === "") {
                 editor.insert(".");
             }

             if (lastToken === "page" || (lastToken.indexOf("page") > -1) || lastToken === "Page" || (lastToken.indexOf("Page") > -1) && (nextToken === "onAppVariablesReady" || (nextToken.indexOf("onAppVariablesReady") > -1)) {
                 editor.insert(".");
                 // Add your custom snipets to this global array
                 self.customSnippets = ["A", "B"];  // Global Array
             } else {
                 editor.insert(".");
             }
         }
   });
```

**For Case 2**

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'myCommand',
    bindKey: {win: 'Ctrl-Space',  mac: 'Command-Space'},
    exec: function(editor) {
        self.customSnippets = ["A", "B"]; //your array of default custom snippets
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But where are you adding the custom snippets if the input is Page.onAppVariablesReady ? I understood case 2

Comment: if (lastToken === "page" || (lastToken.indexOf("page") > -1) || lastToken === "Page" || (lastToken.indexOf("Page") > -1) && (nextToken === "onAppVariablesReady" || (nextToken.indexOf("onAppVariablesReady") > -1)) {
                 editor.insert(".");
                 // Add your custom snipets to this global array
                 self.customSnippets = [];  // Global Array
             }


Here, once your last token is "Page" and next token is "onAppVariablesReady", add your custom tokens

Comment: Check the "If" loop

Comment: Ok Thank You. I will try this